# How to change date that char value in C++?

Tags: c++, char

I am a beginner in C++ programming.

The subject has "changed char's value."
But! my code always call debugging errors....
What is the matter....... :(

Example

```
int main(){

    char c[] = "hey";
    char d[] = "hellow";

    cout <<"befor/"<< c << "," << d << endl;
    f(c, d);

    cout <<"after/"<< c << "," << d << endl;


    save();
}
void f(char* p, char* q) {

    int x = *(char*)p;
    int y = *(char*)q;

    int temp= x;
    y= x;
    y = temp;


}
```

I want to get this value

befor/hey,hellow

after/hellow, hey

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTIh0.png)

Comment: Can you explain please, it is very unclear what problems you are experiencing or what you are trying to accomplish. What is clear is that you are unhappy, but that is sadly, insufficient.

Comment: no error http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=88a670352c63d925

Comment: if you are trying to swap the values of two strings, then you can do `char *temp = p; p = q; q = temp;` in function `f`. But it would be great if you explain your problem in a bit more detail and with more clarity :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to swap the two strings around, but this isn't going to work, I'll try to explain why.

```
int main(){

    char c[] = "hey";
    char d[] = "hellow";

    cout << c << "," << d << endl;
    f(c, d);

    cout << c << "," << d << endl;


    save();
}
void f(char* p, char* q) { 
// When you pass the two strings to this function the arrays turn into
// pointers to the string. 

    int x = *(char*)p; // You now say you want x to be equal to the first 
                       // letter of what p points to, which is "hey". 
                       // So now x equals 'h', although its value is as 
                       // an int.
    int y = *(char*)q; // Here you assign the first letter of "hellow" 
                       // to y. y now equals 'h' also

    int temp= x; // temp now equals 'h'
    y = x; // y now equals 'h' also
    y = temp; // y now equals 'h' also

    // Basically this whole thing does nothing.

}
```

You can have the function swap the pointers around by doing this, though there's probably too much to explain everything.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void f(char** p, char** q);

int main() {

    char* c = "hey";
    char* d = "hellow";

    cout << "befor/" << c << "," << d << endl;

    f(&c, &d);

    cout << "after/" << c << "," << d << endl;

}
void f(char** p, char** q) {

    char* temp = *p;

    *p = *q;
    *q = temp;
}
```

Why is function arguments have to be taken as either pointer to pointer, or reference to pointer, because just pointer will just give the function a copy, and a copy isn't good enough to change the original pointer. Sorry if none of this makes sense, there are a lot of things wrong with your code and I can't really explain everything.

Comment: Why not use references - i.e. `void f(char*& p, char*& q) {`

Comment: @Ed Heal Yeah that would avoid all the dereferencing, hopefully the OP would understand a pointer to pointer better, although I'm not counting on it.

Comment: Thanks to you, I first found out about this. I need to study ' swap ' right now.